# SVG: Can I pass a parameter value to a used element?

Tags: svg

I’m still new to SVG, so I’m unclear on the terminology.

Is there an SVG only way of passing on a parameter value to `use`d element? For example I have hard-coded the text **Name** in the `g` element, but would like to pass it a value from the `use` element.

Currently I create the `g` element without the text and place some text after I `use` it, but there should be a better way.

I have searched widely on the Internet, but I can’t find anything that’s current or relevant to this application.

Some have suggested using JavaScript, but that’s not a general solution, since I won’t be necessarily plugging in to a browser.

```html
<svg width="160" viewBox="0 0 160 120">
    <defs>
        <g id="test">
            <rect width="60" height="40"/>
            <text x="8" y="24" stroke="none" fill="black">Name</text>
        </g>
    </defs>
    <use href="#test" x="00" y="20" fill="aqua" stroke="blue"/>
    <use href="#test" x="80" y="20" fill="orange" stroke="red"/>
    <text y="100">This space for rent</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Some ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422238/svg-about-using-defs-and-use-with-variable-text-values

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **no**.

You can't pass parameters via a `<use>` element. The nearest you can get to customising a used reference is by inheriting certain style properties from the `<use>`, such as colour. You certainly can't customise the actual content of elements, without using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem.

In my experience, you need to pass some parameter and use it like below

```
function generateSVG(width, hight){
    return `<svg viewBox='0 0 160 120'>` + 
           `<defs>`+
           ...
           `<rect width='${width}' height='${height}'` +
           ...
           `</svg>`;
}
```

Now you generate svg using this function.

```
generateSVG(60,40);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript is a general solution if you create your own **Web Component**, supported in all modern Browsers.

```html
<svg-label fill=aqua stroke=blue>Hello Web</svg-label>
<svg-label fill=orange stroke=red>Components!</svg-label>

<script>
  customElements.define("svg-label", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => { // make sure inner DOM is parsed
        let fill = this.attributes.fill.value;
        let stroke = this.attributes.stroke.value;
        let text = this.innerHTML;
        this.innerHTML = `<svg width="100" viewBox="0 0 120 120">`+
           `<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="${fill}" stroke="${stroke}"/>`+
           `<text y="50%" x="8" stroke="none" fill="black">${text}</text>`+
          `</svg>`;
      });
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: I don’t think you can rely on JavaScript if you’re not using a browser.

Comment: That requirement is nowhere mentioned in OPs question. I do wonder why he wants SVGs then? A new toy that can print them on paper without a computer?

Comment: I _am_ the OP, and I’m not sure that comment about the new toy is entirely helpful. The requirement for a browser wasn’t mentioned either. I wanted an SVG only solution, since I plan to embed the SVG in another technology, but not a web browser. And, yes, it might even be printed on paper.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you're after, but you could make some changes to what is a *use*d element, place it inside a group and then just place text on top of it.

```html
<svg width="160" viewBox="0 0 160 120">
    <defs>
        <g id="test">
            <rect width="60" height="40"/>
        </g>
    </defs>
    
    <g transform="translate(0,20)">
        <use href="#test" fill="aqua" stroke="blue" />
        <text x="10" y="25">Name</text>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(80,20)">
        <use href="#test" fill="orange" stroke="red" />
        <text x="10" y="25">Other</text>
    </g>
    
    <text y="100">This space for rent</text>
</svg>
```